# Ainol Novo 10 Hero and Tesco Hudl - can I update the OS?

Tags: updates

I've got a couple of old tablets that don't get updates from the mnaufacturer any more.
Are there any options for a new OS on them - Android, Linux, LineageOS or whatever?

Tablets are

- Tesco Hudl
- Ainol Novo 10 Hero quad core

Comment: See [LineageOS devices page](https://wiki.lineageos.org/devices/). Additionally use your favorite search engine for `CustomROM` plus the device type and you will see if there are alternatives available.

Comment: My tablets aren't listed, is there anything I can do  ?